# Subclass inheritance partial property from super class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have question about  subclass inheritance property from super class in python, I know we can use super inside property to inheritance a property from super class. But what if
my subclass only want to inheritance partial of property? like I have Company class with team property that contain 3 data.
and I only want subclass School have the same department data from Company but not software or pm. What should I do?

```
import json

class Company:
    @property
    def team(self):
        return json.dumps(dict(department='20', software='120', pm='5'))

class School(Company):
    @property
    def team(self):
        j = super().team
        j = json.loads(j) 
        data = {**j, **dict(college='10', board_member='300')}
        return json.dumps(data)

g = Company()
vt = School()
print(g.team) #expected  {"department": "20", "software": "120", "pm": "5"}
print(vt.team) #expected  {"department": "20", "college": "10", "board_member": "300"}
```

Comment: So just remove the key from the dictionary you loaded?

Comment: Put differently: if you want to alter the result that the `team` property produces on the parent class, **just do so**.

Comment: `del j['pm'], j['software']`, or just use `j['department']` in the new dictionary and ignore the rest.

Comment: When you start running into problems like this, it generally means that your parent class is too specific.  Here, it sounds like `Company` is modelling some software company, which are a little like `School`s, but a school is not a company.  Maybe both should inherit from some other class that represents their over lap (`Organization`, for example)